# Need to call Express like use route using Restify

Tags: node.js, typescript, restify

Expresss.use() accepts 2 parameters

```
app.use('/abcd', routeHandler);
```

Restify only supports one

```
restify.use(routeHandler);
```

Referring to workaround on https://github.com/restify/node-restify/issues/289

```
server.use(scopeMiddlewareTo('/prefix', myMiddleware));
```

I'm trying to use this workaround, but getting below error

```
{"code":"InternalError","message":"middleware.call is not a function"}
```

I'm using Typescript, but even the JS code while debugging and middleware.call() is not found.

Basically I have routes in separate files and do not wish to use restify.get(), restify.post() in main.ts. The separate files act as sub-apps.

Comment: what version are you using?, i checked de docs (http://restify.com/) and in the first Server example you can see `server.get('/hello/:name', respond);`, that looks very expressy to me.

Comment: Ok, as i can see in the docs, the use function is only for middleware purposes, not related to routing, because restify focuses on rest api, its a little more fine grained, so you need to define all your http verbs, and `restify.use` is only to run a middleware before the route gets matched.

Comment: @Sebastián Espinosa I was expecting restify.use() to accept two params like Express does. Anyway, so express accepts url and route, but restify accepts only one param which is middleware, and middleware is not route. Got it. So I'll try to create a middleware to return sub-app routes and bind it to Restify.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/restify-prefix-route.

```
var applyPrefix = require('restify-prefix-route');

server.pre(applyPrefix('/v1'));
```

use this to add prefix in all routes.